# Mock object in PHPUnit is not invoked

Tags: php, zend-framework, mocking, phpunit, zf3

I have this code in my PHPUnit test and it's trying to mock a table entity. But when i try to run it i get this error.

> Expectation failed for method name is equal to
>    when invoked 1 time(s). Method was expected
>   to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

```
public function testFetchSingleById()
{
    $mockJobTable = $this->getMockBuilder('Job\Table\JobTable')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['fetchSingleById'])
        ->getMock();

    $firstDateRun = new \DateTime('2016-06-03');
    $firstDateRun = $firstDateRun->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $job = new JobEntity();
    $job->exchangeArray([
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'parse',
        'params' => '--dry-run',
        'setFirstDateRun' => $firstDateRun,
        'period' => '* * * * *'
    ]);

    $mockJobTable->expects($this->once())
                 ->method('fetchSingleById')
                 ->with(1)
                 ->will($this->returnValue($job));
}
```

method that i am testing:

```
class JobTable extends TableGateway implements JobTableInterface
{
    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter, JobEntity $entity)
    {
        $resultSet = new ResultSet();
        $resultSet->setArrayObjectPrototype($entity);
        parent::__construct('job', $adapter, null, $resultSet);
    }

    public function fetchSingleById($id)
    {
        $select = $this->getSql()->select();
        $select->where->equalTo('id', $id);
        return $this->selectWith($select)->current();
    }
}
```

I am using ZF3.

I'm missing something but I don't know what.

Comment: please share all the test code and the method under test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sets up an expectation and then does nothing with it. There has to be something that actually invokes `fetchSingleById` on the mock object. Also, from the name of the test it looks like it's mocking the very method it's supposed to test. There's no need to test PHPUnit in a test case that's not part of PHPUnit itself.